# Is there a way I can make a list out of this?

Tags: python, list

So I programmed this code to print out how many times a number would be printed in the list that I provided, and the output works, but I want to put all the values that I get into a list, how can I do that?
This is my code...

```
i = [5,5,7,9,9,9,9,9,8,8]
def num_list(i):
    return [(i.count(x),x) for x in set(i)]

for tv in num_list(i):
    if tv[1] > 1:
        print(tv)
```

The output that I get is

```
(2, 8)
(5, 9)
(2, 5)
(1, 7)
```

but I want the output to be like

```
[2,8,5,9,2,5,1,7)
```

How can I do that??

Comment: Mmmmm don't use `[(i.count(x),x) for x in set(i)]`. It's potentially very inefficient. use a `collections.Counter`

Comment: how do you get that order? why wouldnt (1,7) come before (2,5) ?  for that matter why would it not be `[(2,5),(1,7),(5,9) ,(2,8)]` .... maybe order doesnt matter?

Comment: Note that StackOverflow users love to see code in questions. Also, in your description you are referring to code, which is invisible after your edit. Please do not change questions in a way which makes them unanswerable, even not after you got answers. Your statement of desired output and the output you get is for example very important for an answerable question. So I undo the obviously accidental removal of code and releveant information.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
tvlist = []
for tv in num_list(i):
    if tv[1] > 1:
        tvlist.extend(tv)

print(tvlist)
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
tvlist = [x for tv in num_list(i) if tv[1] > 1 for x in tv]
```

Also your function could just simply be `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def num_list(i):
    return Counter(i).items()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
flattened_iter = itertools.chain.from_iterable(num_list(i))
print(list(flattened_iter))
```

is how i would flatten a list

as mentioned by everyone else collections.Counter is likely to be significantly better performance for large lists...

if you would rather implement it yourself you can pretty easily

```
def myCounter(a_list):
    counter = {}
    for item in a_list:
        # in modern python versions order is preserved in dicts
        counter[item] = counter.get(item,0) + 1
    for unique_item in counter:
        # make it a generator just for ease
        # we will just yield twice to create a flat list
        yield counter[unique_item]
        yield unique_item


i = [5,5,7,9,9,9,9,9,8,8]
print(list(myCounter(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `collections.Counter` is more efficient. This paired with `itertools.chain` will get you your desired result:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

i = [5,5,7,9,9,9,9,9,8,8]

r = list(chain(*((v, k) for k, v in Counter(i).items() if v > 1)))
print(r)
```

---

```
[2, 5, 5, 9, 2, 8]
```

Without `itertools.chain`

```
r = []
for k, v in Counter(i).items():
    if v > 1:
        r.extend((v, k))
```